# How to call debounce method within one function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, lodash

I use React Hooks and lodash. After user clicks a button, I need to clear one state and after one second update another state. I managed to create this:

```
 const FirstAddTodo = type => {
    setEditor({ ...editor, todoTitle: '' });
    SecondAddTodo(type);
  };

  const SecondAddTodo = _.debounce(type => {
    dispatch({ type, value: editor.todoTitle });
  }, 1000);
```

It works perfectly, but is there a possibility to combine these two function into one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but maybe this is what you want

```
 const FirstAddTodo = type => {
    setEditor({ ...editor, todoTitle: '' });

    _.debounce(type => {
      dispatch({ type, value: editor.todoTitle });
    }, 1000)(type);
  };
```

If you are confused, I can explain.

`_.debounce` will return a function and when you do `SecondAddTodo(type)` you are calling the retuned function, so if you add another `()` in the end of `_.debounce`, you are calling the returned function.

Here is an example on how to understand it better

```js
let a = function (){ console.log('nested function'); }
let b = function (){ return a }
let c = function (){ return b }
let d = function (){ return c }

console.log(d)
console.log(d())
console.log(d()())
console.log(d()()())
console.log(d()()()())
```